# Cannot modify coordinates of an actor and draw him in different places niether

Tags: libgdx, coordinates, actor, scene2d

Firstable, sorry for my english. I have this issue that's driving me crazy.
I just only want the actor movement with the arrow keys, but he doesn't move, why?
Here's the Screen class code:

```
public class PantallaTest implements Screen{

JuegoTest juego;
Texture gato;
Sprite gatoSprite;
Stage escenario;
GatoActor gatoActor;

public PantallaTest(JuegoTest juego) {

    this.juego = juego;
}

@Override
public void show() {

    escenario = new Stage(new FitViewport(320f, 320f));
    gato = juego.manager.get("cat_stand.png", Texture.class);
    gatoSprite = new Sprite(gato);
    gatoActor = new GatoActor(gatoSprite);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(escenario);
    escenario.addActor(gatoActor);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    escenario.draw();
    escenario.act();

    updateJuego();
}

private void updateJuego() {

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)){
        gatoActor.setX(gatoActor.getX()-2);
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)){
        gatoActor.setX(gatoActor.getX()+2);
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)){
        gatoActor.setY(gatoActor.getY()+2);
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN)){
        gatoActor.setY(gatoActor.getY()-2);
    }
}
```

And the actor's code:

```
public class GatoActor extends Actor {

    Sprite sprite;

    public GatoActor(Sprite sprite) {

        this.sprite = sprite;
        this.setSize(sprite.getWidth(),sprite.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

        Color col = getColor();
        batch.setColor(col.r, col.g, col.b, col.a * parentAlpha);

        batch.draw(sprite,getX(),getY(), getOriginX(), getOriginY(), getWidth(), getHeight(), getScaleX(), getScaleY(), getRotation());
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        rectGato.setPosition(getX(),getY());
        super.act(delta);
    }
}
```

The code of the main class

```
public class JuegoTest extends Game{

PantallaTest pTest;
AssetManager manager;
SpriteBatch batch;

@Override
public void create() {

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    manager = new AssetManager();
    manager.load("cat_stand.png", Texture.class);
    manager.load("platform.png", Texture.class);

    pTest = new PantallaTest(this);

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

    manager.dispose();
    batch.dispose();
    super.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render() {

    if(manager.update()){
        this.setScreen(pTest);
    }
    super.render();
}


}
```

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you get any errors when building your project? The only problem I had was in your GatoActor class, in the act method, you used:

```
rectGato.setPosition(getX(),getY());
```

I noticed you never defined rectoGato anywhere else, and you probably meant to set the position of the sprite, so I changed it to:

```
sprite.setPosition(getX(),getY());
```

Now everything works fine for me, the actor moves with the key presses. Hope this helps.

Edit*
For the main class after loading images you should try

manager.finishLoading();

And then set the screen instead of doing it all in the render method. What you had before seems right but you should try this to see if it works. That's my guess.

Comment: Object rectGato should not appear. When I load the texture to create the sprite without using an AssetManager, it works fine. That's the problem. I create the AssetManager in the main class and it loads the resources fine, but I can't update the coordinates or draw the actor in other place.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the main class when you used the AssestManager?